# Extracting JSON-data from CSV file

Tags: json, r, csv

I'm trying to extract a JSON data which is a column in a CSV file. So far I've come to the point where I've extracted the column in the right format, but the formatting is only correct when the variable type is factor. But I can't convert a factor to a json-file using the `jsonlite` package.

```
[1] {"id":509746197991998767,"visibility":{"percentage":100,"time":149797,"visible1":true,"visible2":false,"visible3":false,"activetab":true},"interaction":{"mouseovercount":1,"mouseovertime":1426,"videoplaytime":0,"engagementtime":0,"expandtime":0,"exposuretime":35192}}
```

Another approach is to use `stringsAsFactors = F` when importing, but I'm struggling in getting the formatting right, where each entry looks like this:

```
[1] "{\"id\":509746197991998767,\"visibility\":{\"percentage\":100,\"time\":149797,\"visible1\":true,\"visible2\":false,\"visible3\":false,\"activetab\":true},\"interaction\":{\"mouseovercount\":1,\"mouseovertime\":1426,\"videoplaytime\":0,\"engagementtime\":0,\"expandtime\":0,\"exposuretime\":35192}}"
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I simply just want to exract the `JSON` files that sits inside a CSV file.

Heres a small example of the CSV file:

```
"","CookieID","UnloadVars"
"1",-8857188784608690176,"{""id"":509746197991998767,""visibility"":{""percentage"":100,""time"":149797,""visible1"":true,""visible2"":false,""visible3"":false,""activetab"":true},""interaction"":{""mouseovercount"":1,""mouseovertime"":1426,""videoplaytime"":0,""engagementtime"":0,""expandtime"":0,""exposuretime"":35192}}"
"2",-1695626857458244096,"{""id"":2917654329769114342,""visibility"":{""percentage"":46,""time"":0,""visible1"":false,""visible2"":false,""visible3"":false,""activetab"":true}}"
"3",437299165071669184,"{""id"":2252707957388071809,""visibility"":{""percentage"":99,""time"":10168,""visible1"":true,""visible2"":false,""visible3"":false,""activetab"":true},""interaction"":{""mouseovercount"":0,""mouseovertime"":0,""videoplaytime"":0,""engagementtime"":0,""expandtime"":0,""exposuretime"":542},""clicks"":[{""x"":105,""y"":449}]}"
"4",292660729552227520,""
"5",7036383942916227072,"{""id"":2299674593327687292,""visibility"":{""percentage"":76,""time"":1145,""visible1"":true,""visible2"":false,""visible3"":false,""activetab"":true},""interaction"":{""mouseovercount"":0,""mouseovertime"":0,""videoplaytime"":0,""engagementtime"":0,""expandtime"":0,""exposuretime"":74},""clicks"":[{""x"":197,""y"":135},{""x"":197,""y"":135}]}"
```

Regards,

Frederik.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the csv.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've added a small sample to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- readr::read_csv('"","CookieID","UnloadVars"
"1",-8857188784608690176,"{""id"":509746197991998767,""visibility"":{""percentage"":100,""time"":149797,""visible1"":true,""visible2"":false,""visible3"":false,""activetab"":true},""interaction"":{""mouseovercount"":1,""mouseovertime"":1426,""videoplaytime"":0,""engagementtime"":0,""expandtime"":0,""exposuretime"":35192}}"
"2",-1695626857458244096,"{""id"":2917654329769114342,""visibility"":{""percentage"":46,""time"":0,""visible1"":false,""visible2"":false,""visible3"":false,""activetab"":true}}"
"3",437299165071669184,"{""id"":2252707957388071809,""visibility"":{""percentage"":99,""time"":10168,""visible1"":true,""visible2"":false,""visible3"":false,""activetab"":true},""interaction"":{""mouseovercount"":0,""mouseovertime"":0,""videoplaytime"":0,""engagementtime"":0,""expandtime"":0,""exposuretime"":542},""clicks"":[{""x"":105,""y"":449}]}"
"4",292660729552227520,""
"5",7036383942916227072,"{""id"":2299674593327687292,""visibility"":{""percentage"":76,""time"":1145,""visible1"":true,""visible2"":false,""visible3"":false,""activetab"":true},""interaction"":{""mouseovercount"":0,""mouseovertime"":0,""videoplaytime"":0,""engagementtime"":0,""expandtime"":0,""exposuretime"":74},""clicks"":[{""x"":197,""y"":135},{""x"":197,""y"":135}]}"',
col_types = "-cc")
```

Using `jsonlite::fromJSON` on each separate value, then `tidyr::unnest`

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(.x) 
  if (is.na(.x) || .x == "") data.frame()[1, ] else 
    as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(.x))

df %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(UnloadVars = lapply(UnloadVars, f)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("id")), as.character)

# A tibble: 6 x 16
#               CookieID                  id visibility.percentage visibility.time visibility.visible1 visibility.visible2 visibility.visible3 visibility.activetab interaction.mouseovercount interaction.mouseovertime interaction.videoplaytime interaction.engagementtime interaction.expandtime interaction.exposuretime clicks.x clicks.y
#                  <chr>               <chr>                 <int>           <int>               <lgl>               <lgl>               <lgl>                <lgl>                      <int>                     <int>                     <int>                      <int>                  <int>                    <int>    <int>    <int>
# 1 -8857188784608690176  509746197991998784                   100          149797                TRUE               FALSE               FALSE                 TRUE                          1                      1426                         0                          0                      0                    35192       NA       NA
# 2 -1695626857458244096 2917654329769114112                    46               0               FALSE               FALSE               FALSE                 TRUE                         NA                        NA                        NA                         NA                     NA                       NA       NA       NA
# 3   437299165071669184 2252707957388071936                    99           10168                TRUE               FALSE               FALSE                 TRUE                          0                         0                         0                          0                      0                      542      105      449
# 4   292660729552227520                <NA>                    NA              NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                   NA                         NA                        NA                        NA                         NA                     NA                       NA       NA       NA
# 5  7036383942916227072 2299674593327687168                    76            1145                TRUE               FALSE               FALSE                 TRUE                          0                         0                         0                          0                      0                       74      197      135
# 6  7036383942916227072 2299674593327687168                    76            1145                TRUE               FALSE               FALSE                 TRUE                          0                         0                         0                          0                      0                       74      197      135
```

Comment: Oups. I did something wrong and somehow duplicated row 5 into row 4. Very weird. Don't use this yet.

Comment: *Edit:* actually I didn't, but I lost row 4. Duplication of last row comes from the last array `[{""x"":197,""y"":135},{""x"":197,""y"":135}]`. I still have to spare row 4.

Comment: Ok, I've now fixed my answer. You should get 6 rows and not 5, *as expected*.

Comment: Wow. This is such a neat solution. Still haven't gone through and understood everything, but there's much to learn here. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I used readr::read_csv to read in your sample data set.

```
> df <- readr::read_csv('~/sample.csv')
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  CookieID = col_double(),
  UnloadVars = col_character()
)
```

As you can see the UnloadVars are read in as characters and not factors. If I now examine the first value in the UnloadVars columns I see the following which matches what you get,

```
> df$UnloadVars[1]
[1] "{\"id\":509746197991998767,\"visibility\":{\"percentage\":100,\"time\":149797,\"visible1\":true,\"visible2\":false,\"visible3\":false,\"activetab\":true},\"interaction\":{\"mouseovercount\":1,\"mouseovertime\":1426,\"videoplaytime\":0,\"engagementtime\":0,\"expandtime\":0,\"exposuretime\":35192}}"
```

Now, I use jsonlite::fromJSON,

```
> j <- jsonlite::fromJSON(df$UnloadVars[1])
> j
$id
[1] 5.097462e+17

$visibility
$visibility$percentage
[1] 100

$visibility$time
[1] 149797

$visibility$visible1
[1] TRUE

$visibility$visible2
[1] FALSE

$visibility$visible3
[1] FALSE

$visibility$activetab
[1] TRUE


$interaction
$interaction$mouseovercount
[1] 1

$interaction$mouseovertime
[1] 1426

$interaction$videoplaytime
[1] 0

$interaction$engagementtime
[1] 0

$interaction$expandtime
[1] 0

$interaction$exposuretime
[1] 35192
```

Which I believe is what you need since JSONs are parsed as lists in R.

Comment: Ah, of course.Thanks SO much. I forgot to enter to result with [1]. But now I'm stuck with a parsed JSON that is understandable in my CSV file. I want to add the entries as columns in my original dataframe (csv), say for example the id. How do I go about that?

Comment: Are there specific components of the JSON that you want to set as columns in your df?

Answer (score 0):

It can be very tricky to deal with JSON data. As a general guide line, you should always strive to have your data in a data frame. This, however, is not always possible. In the specific case, I don't see a way you can have both `visibility` and `interaction` values at once in a nicely formatted data frame.

What I will do next is to extract the information from `interaction` into a data frame.

Load required packages and read the data

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- read.csv("sample.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then remove unvalid JSON

```
# remove rows without JSON (in this case, the 4th row)
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(UnloadVars != "")
```

Transform each JSON into a list and put them into `UnloadVars` column. If you didn't know that, it is possible to have list column in a data frame. This can be very useful.

```
out <- data_frame(CookieID = numeric(), 
                  UnloadVars = list())

for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  new_row <- data_frame(CookieID = df[row, ]$CookieID,
                        UnloadVars = list(jsonlite::fromJSON(df[row, ]$UnloadVars)))

  out <- bind_rows(out, new_row)
}

out
```

We can now extract the IDs from the lists in `Unload Vars`. This is straight forward because there is only one ID per list.

```
out <- out %>% 
  mutate(id = map_chr(UnloadVars, ~ .$id))
```

This final part can seem a bit intimidating. But what I am doing here is taking interaction part from `UnloadVars` column and putting it into a `interaction` column. I then transform each row from `interaction`, which is a list, into a data frame with two columns: `key` and `value`. `key` contains the name of the interaction metric and `value` its value. I finally unnest it, so we get rid of list columns and end up with a nicely formatted data frame.

```
unpack_list <- function(obj, key_name) {
  as.data.frame(obj) %>% 
    gather(key) %>% 
    return()
}

df_interaction <- out %>% 
    mutate(interaction = map(UnloadVars, ~ .$interaction)) %>% 
    mutate(interaction = map(interaction, ~ unpack_list(.x, key))) %>% 
    unnest(interaction)

df_interaction
```

The solution is not very elegant, but gets the job done. You could apply the same logic to extract information from visibility.

Comment: What is `unpack_list`?

Comment: @Aurèle, I forgot to add it. It was a custom function I have written. Thanks for noting that